# Why can't I call a method I define in a field?

Tags: java, oop, methods

Consider the following code.

**B.java**

```
public class B {

    void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

}
```

**A.java**

```
public class A {

    B b = new B() {
        void lorem() {
            System.out.println("Lorem");
        }
    };

    void bar() {
        // Why can't I call b.lorem() here?
        b.foo();
    }

}
```

Why can't I call `b.lorem()` in `bar()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lorem` is a method of an anonymous sub-class of B. Therefore you can't call it by using a reference of class B, and since it's anonymous, you can't cast `b` to a type that contains `lorem`.